# .htaccess redirects on masked domains, only written to take effect when specific domains are in use

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite set up on an Apache server. For SEO reasons, I'm trying to shift as many possible JS redirects to HTTP 301s in the .htaccess file. Because the domains on this multisite are masked, all of these domains share one top-level directory and one .htaccess file. Because of this, I am unable to make every redirect a simple

```
Redirect 301 /example/ https://example.com/example/
```

Example being, if we have one service that closes a location in Austin TX, another service that still has one open in Austin TX, and both URLs are set up as "example.com/austin/", I can't have a catch-all redirect sending "/austin/" to one place. This creates a ton of potential conflicts.

---

So I'm trying to create redirects that ONLY take effect when a specific masked domain is in use. Below is the code I'm using, but it's not working, notice I'm making sure that both trailing slashes and non-trailing slashes are covered:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^old1$ https://example.com/new1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^old1/$ https://example.com/new1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^old12$ https://example.com/new12/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^old12/$ https://example.com/new12/ [R=301,NC,L]
#...
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: A RewriteCond only affects the next following RewriteRule, not multiple ones.

Comment: _“that both trailing slashes and non-trailing slashes are covered”_ – that doesn’t need two rules, you can make the trailing slash optional by using the `?` quantifier on it. `^foo/?$`

Comment: @04FS I updated these to look like 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^old1/?$ https://example.com/new1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^old12/?$ https://example.com/new12/ [R=301,NC,L]

They're still not working, unfortunately.

Comment: @04FS

I was able to solve the issue. The /? tip was great, but the underlying issue was another rewrite rule above all of them that forced a trailing slash. All I had to do was move it to the bottom of all the redirect rules and it worked out. The RewriteCond did actually cover multiple RewriteRule(s) so I'm not finding that to be an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @04FS nope you were 100% right about the only one RewriteRule thing. Found out about that the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I had a rule in there to force trailing slashes.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Because it was above all the redirects, it voided them. I moved that rule below them and it fixed it.